# Find out if Android WebView is showing cached page

Tags: android, caching, webview

I'm making an Android application that, among other things, shows websites in a webview. As far as I understand, the webview automatically shows a cached version of the page if a connection can't be established.

Is there any way to find out if the page shown has been fetched from the server or cache?

Maybe even how old the cached page is.

This is to be able to notify the user if he/she is viewing old information.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try a hack - at first set WebView's [cache mode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setCacheMode(int)) to `WebSettings.NO_CACHE` and load the URL. Then, create a custom WebChromeClient like this:

```
final String urlToLoad = "http://www.my-url.com"; 
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
            String description, String failingUrl)
    {
        if (view.getSettings().getCacheMode() == WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE && urlToLoad.equals(failingUrl))
        {
            view.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ONLY);
            view.loadUrl(urlToLoad);
            return;
        }
        else
        if (urlToLoad.equals(failingUrl))
        {
            // cache failed as well, load a local resource as last resort
            // or inform the user
        }
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
    }
});
webview.loadUrl(urlToLoad);
```

Comment: This is still such a hack. Why is there no way to check if a cache exists for a given URL? EDIT: And why does Android call onReceivedError() if a cache exists?

Comment: It work only if you set "WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT" at first. Because if you set WebSettings.NO_CACHE at the first the web page never save to cache even when successfully loaded.
 ( NOTE :: also update the if conditions in the 'onReceivedError' to view.getSettings().getCacheMode() == WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT && urlToLoad.equals(failingUrl) )

Answer (score 0):

Since the WebView work like the browser the answer is no. 
There are some hacky way to detect that situation.

Or an alternative solution would be preventing the page from being cached (see WebView documentation)